# Application crashes or hangs due to openTimeOut setting

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

In my application, i've set the openTimeOut to 1 minute. Now if the service is stopped or server is not running then it causes the problem.

I need to load the forms on the basis of output from the service. I call the service while loading the content of the form. Now if the server is stopped it will hang the UI till the openTimeOut of the service. Main issue is , application uses multiple services and for some other service the timeout is 35 seconds and if it timeouts then it is re-starting the application and my service is still in the openTimeOut mode which results in crashing of the application.

What could be the best solution for this problem.

My question is what is the best way to handle this condition - reduce the openTimeOut or call the service on different thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely call the service on a different thread (or, if you use an auto-generated service proxy, you can switch `Async` versions of the methods which amounts to the same thing). The UI thread should not be dependent on long-running operations or those that may block.

The value of `OpenTimeOut` will not significant as far as hanging the app (because that will stop happening), but you may want to lower it a bit because 1 minute is perhaps too long to wait in order to discover that no connectivity to the service exists.